# A Crash With Xcode 10+ And Swift 5

Tags: swift

```
// tableView is var in self, not lazy var
tableView = UITableView.init(frame: CGRect.zero, style: UITableView.Style.grouped)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
tableView.register(AVHomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AVHomeTableViewCell")
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

//---------------------------------------

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionDataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard sectionDataSource[section].list != nil else {
        return 0
    }       
    return sectionDataSource[section].list!.count
}
```

when the code run to `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`,
the `func tableView(_ tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:)` be called, 
but not call `numberOfSections(in tableView:)`,
and now sectionDataSource is empty, `sectionDataSource[section]` lead to crash, if fix `sectionDataSource[section]` other error will be thowed! Like cell layout Confused.

How to make sure the datasource call sequence!
I do not kown how to resolve the bug!

Answer (score 0):

If list does not exist, you will get the crash, because you are force unwrapping it. Try this to test if there is actually a list:

(Disclaimer: typed in browser, not tested in Xcode)

```
guard let dataSource = sectionDataSource, let list = dataSource[section].list else { return 0 }

return list.count
```

Comment: Thank You! But I want to make sure the datasource Call sequence, if not other error will be throwed

Comment: What do you mean by "datasource call sequence" ? Maybe you can add the code for `sectionDataSource`.